# jscolor onchange callback does not get triggered

Tags: javascript, jscript, jscolor

I'm currently developing a simple webpage that will be used to control a couple of RGB LED-Strips.
To select the desired colors I want to use jscolor-color pickers as they seem quite easy to use.

The problem is, that the callback function never gets executed when a new color is selected by the user. 
If I use the onFineChange event, implemented in the jscolor library the callback fires as intended, but as I want to execute a function only when the mouse is released I want to use the onchange event. With the following code the onchange callback never gets executed.

I hope someone can help me out.
Cheers guys!

```
<html>
<input class="jscolor {valueElement:null}" onchange="getColor(this)" style="border:none" id="color1">
</html>

<script>
function getColor(picker){
          console.log("Callback");
}    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers use the callback function when you left the element focus, if you want to get the real change progress you can use the onkeyup/down event.

Edit:
if you use this js lib http://jscolor.com/examples/ then your code should work when you delete "{valueElement:null}"

Comment: Thank you very much! 
That indeed solved the problem, although I don't really know why, because these attributes seem pretty unrelated to me.
I now have the valueElement enabled and made the text invisible by setting it transparent in the jscolor source file.

Answer (score 0):

onchange -> onChange   (javascript is case sensitive)